# In SystemVerilog, must nets be declared with the **logic** data type?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm reading Sutherland's "RTL Modeling with SystemVerilog ..." book. On pages 77 and 79 he makes the following claims respectively:

> The *data type* must be the keyword **logic**, which can be specified explicitly or implicitly inferred.

And

> Nets are declared by specifying a net *type* and an optional *data type*. The data type must be the 4-state **logic** data type, or a user-defined type derived from 4-state **logic** data types.

However, neither verilator 3.874 nor Vivado 2018.1 have any issues compiling/linting the following code snippet:

```
module foo
(input  wire  logic should_be_fine,
 output uwire bit   nets_can_only_be_logic);

  assign nets_can_only_be_logic = should_be_fine;

endmodule: foo
```

With my current understanding, **bit** is a 2-state data type different from **logic**, so the tools should at least warn that a net type cannot be declared with that data type. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IEEE 1800-2017 LRM is the definitive source. Section 6.7.1 says a valid net data type shall be "*A 4-state integral type, including a packed array or packed structure.*"

Verilator and synthesis tools work in 2-state mode only, so they don't need to interpret the difference between `bit` and `logic`. They also can't handle nets with multiple drivers. You need 4-state logic to deal with that. Other tools generate a syntax error with this code.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer. I just read section 6.7.1 and confirmed what you mentioned. However, I was still able to synthesize and even program the simple design above in Vivado. I'm assuming the tools simply relax some of the language requirements.

Comment: Hey @dave_59, this peaked my interest again. When you say 'synthesis tools work in 2-state mode only', do you mean fpga synthesis tools? I was under the impression that ASIC tools can also 'synthesize'.

Comment: I mean FPGA or ASIC synthesis tools. `bit` or `logic` makes no difference with the hardware they generate.

Comment: Couldn't ASIC's work with 4-valued logic by for example inferring tristate buffers to deal with 'z, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Synthesis tools *could*, but they *don't* want to be responsible for burning up your device. You really want to manually place tri-state buffers on the periphery of your design. IMHO, Verilator and Synthesis tools should report using a `bit` type on a net as an error to follow the LRM correctly making interoperability smoother.

Answer (score -1):

I used to have that book (left it at my old job). You can definitely use wire still in SV. Stu's book is great, but it sounds like this is a mistake (RIP Stu) or there's surrounding text that you omitted that makes it clear. Go to the LRM to be sure.

Edit : Just realized this was about bit vs logic. Stu's book is specifically about synthesizable code. Maybe that's why he says only logic is OK?